# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "" (at offset 0)

Tags: java, android

I've read many answers to this problem but no answer solves my problem

I am trying to parse this string :

`"2013-10-07T23:21:00+01:00"`

to a Date object with the simpledateformat :

`"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"`

but it keeps producing the error:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "" (at offset 0)

Note: I am trying this on Android, I'm a beginner.

Comment: Your timestamp is a ISO compliant timestamp, this answer gives you more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date

Comment: Can you please post the actual source and the stacktrace?

Comment: Welcome to SO. As @GyroGearless says, please consider add your code and full stacktrace. This information is always useful to help you.

Comment: From the exception it looks like you are trying to parse an empty string. Check the string before the parse function.

Answer (score 2):

Try with following code

```
public static Calendar parseDate(String dateTimeStr)
            throws ParseException {
        Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        String s = dateTimeStr.replace("Z", "+00:00");
        try {
            s = s.substring(0, 22) + s.substring(23);
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            throw new ParseException("Invalid length", 0);
        }
        Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").parse(s);
        calendar.setTime(date);
        return calendar;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

If you use java 7, you can use:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX
```

You can check more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: The 'X' is available since Java 7.

Comment: Android doesn't support Java 7, unfortunately